# Quarkus reading application.properties from the @QuarkusTest

Tags: java, quarkus

In my `application.properties` I have

```
quarkus.http.root-path=/my-service/api/v2
```

and it works when I run the app and hit the url. (It reads the config on start).

But when I run it from the test:

```
@QuarkusTest
@Tag("integration")
public class MyResourceTest {
    @Test
    public void testMyEndpoint() {

        given()
                .when().get("/my-service/api/v2/init")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(is("{}"));
    }
```

I got `404`. But it works if do `get("/init")`

Seems that the Test does not know about the `application.properties`.

I tried to put  `application.properties` to `test/resources` folder (similar to what I would do if work with `Spring Bootstrap` app)

I tried this, assuming it uses the `test` profile when I run test (did not work):

```
%test.quarkus.http.root-path=/my-service/api/v2
```

**UPDATE:**
 I was able to read my database config though, adding %test to the test/resources/application.properties

```
#test
%test.quarkus.datasource.url=vertx-reactive:postgresql://mydb-url:5432/mydb
```

But the `quarkus.http.root` seems different thing.

**Question** is:

- how to read `quarkus.http.root` from properties files for from the integration test? (could not find it in the doc).

Comment: I was looking for `quarkus.http.root` on [quarkus all config](https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config) but didn't find it. Is it a custom config?

Comment: You will see it when generate all possible configs for your current installed extensions: https://quarkus.io/guides/config#generating-configuration-for-your-application - seems the quarkus.http.root is one of the core/web ones

Comment: @ses could you check with curl or browser if the endpoint is indeed exposed on the shorter path in the tests?

Comment: /init path, shorter path works

Comment: sounds like a bug, could you open an issue in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/ ? It would be great help if you could also attach a minimal reproducer to the issue.

Comment: ok:https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5494

Answer (score 1):

This is because the Restassured integration is aware of the modified root path, so it transparently adjusts the requests it sends. When you request /init it will automatically map to /my-service/api/v2/init